# When should I use NSURL instead of NSString and vice versa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring, nsurl

This is not a question about a pertinent problem. It's a question by which I try to deepen my understanding of Objective-C or more specific Cocoa Foundation.

When dealing with uploading and download files from a server to my apps, I'm constantly torn between using `NSURL` or `NSString` for all things path related. Of course when there's an existing API I just use it according to the specs. But when I store my own paths or create custom classes that deal with them, I'm confused which of the two would be the better pick.

`NSString` is used everywhere and it has convenience methods like `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` and `stringByAppendingPathExtension:`. I can easily convert to NSURL by creating a new instance with `[NSURL URLWithString:@"string"]` and the other way around by calling `[url path]` on an NSURL instance. But the difference is there for a reason, right?

My confusion grows when I look at header files of something like NSFileManager. These two methods are pretty close together:

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error;
- (BOOL)copyItemAtURL:(NSURL *)srcURL toURL:(NSURL *)dstURL error:(NSError **)error NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);
```

Why would I choose to use one over the other, especially when conversions between the two are made so easily? And why does Apple go through the trouble of creating near-identical APIs for using both data types?

If someone has the deeper insight for when to use NSURL instead of NSString for your own classes handling file paths and remote urls, please do share! Cheers.

Comment: What about when referencing files on the local filesystem?

Comment: What do you mean? `NSURL` has an [extensive set of methods dealing with file system URLs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW25).

Comment: So does NSString.  It seems NSURL is generally preferred, but I am wondering if that carries to local files as well.

Comment: For myself, I just resorted to using `NSURL`, unless I absolutely need to use `NSString`, like when dealing with a lot of `NSFileManager`'s API. I guess there is no canonical answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally for path related operations you should prefer `NSURL` over `NSString` because the path information can be stored more efficiently in `NSURL` (according to the class reference for `NSFileManager`). So I would recommend that for your APIs you use also `NSURL`.

Also `NSURL` has `URLByAppendingPathComponent:` and `URLByAppendingPathExtension:` so convenience is served as well :-)

Comment: +1 Also, upcoming Mac App Store sandboxing rules require permissions, which (as I understand it) are stored within the NSURL itself, making it easier to archive filesystem access for later use.

Comment: I think _all other things being equal_ a big argument for using NSURL APIs is _they're not NSStrings_. It's pretty easy to mix up things of the same type, and NSURLs are used a lot less often than NSStrings. Consider: `[fm copyItemAtPath:name …]` will compile but not work, since you probably wanted `[fm copyItemAtPath:path …]`.

Answer (score 8):

`NSUrl` knows how to handle virtually any king of urls — not just Web-adresses and splits it into easy accessible chunks:

- protocol or scheme (http, ftp, telnet,ssh)
- username and the password (for example for ssh: ssh://user:password@host.domain.org)
- host name
- port
- path
- GET parameters

Now you can easily asks the url-object for this chunks, while in a string there might be the need for excessive if rules or complicated regex's.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, +1. I had to choose whom to give the mark, and @applaudierend had the reference in there.