# What is the reason for NSFileManager's inconsistent use of NSURL?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I read somewhere that Apple encourages the use of NSURL over NSString in terms of paths and file locations, and this is becoming more obvious in new(er) API's - correct me if I am wrong. This [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769219/when-should-i-use-nsurl-instead-of-nsstring-and-vice-versa) deals with this topic in particular.

However, I noticed that some API's seem inconsistent regarding the use of NSURL and NSString - NSFileManager in particular. For example, NSFileManager has a method fileExistsAtPath: (which takes a NSString as the only argument), but there is no equivalent that takes a NSURL as the argument. To remove a file, though, there is a method that takes a NSString and an equivalent method that takes a NSURL.

Is there a reason for this discrepancy or has this historically grown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because they want to discourage the use of existence checks. As the header rather diplomatically puts it:

> The following methods are of limited utility. Attempting to predicate behavior based on the current state of the filesystem or a particular file on the filesystem is encouraging odd behavior in the face of filesystem race conditions. It's far better to attempt an operation (like loading a file or creating a directory) and handle the error gracefully than it is to try to figure out ahead of time whether the operation will succeed.

Comment: That is a great point. Checking for file existence is indeed not always the best approach.

Comment: If you're desperate to check a file's existence (and you shouldn't be ideally), -[NSURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:] is the successor to -fileExistsAtPath:

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that it is just a bit of legacy code on the NSString side, as it does look like they are going toward NSURL for what might roughly be called file operations.

Also, the SO question you referenced makes a good point regarind why NSURL is more desireable:

> Also NSURL has URLByAppendingPathComponent: and URLByAppendingPathExtension: so convenience is served as well :-)

Comment: `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` and `stringByAppendingPathExtension:` have been around for longer. :-)

Comment: @Ahruman ah ok so yeah it looks like the NSString stuff might be legacy.

Comment: @Ahruman I was thinking the same when I was reading that other Stack Overflow question. There is quite a bit of overlap, which isn't surprising if Apple wants to push the use of NSURL.