# NSArray initWithObjects only initializing with some of the objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I've encountered a weird issue thats causing me quite the headache.  I am initializing an NSArray object using initWithObjects.  I'm passing in 7 objects but immediately afterwords, if I log the count of the array, I only have a count of 3.  Has anyone else seen this? I've used this method countless times with no problem before and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  The code is below:

```
-(DMORecipe *) saveRecipe:(NSNumber *)recipeID recipeTitle:(NSString *)title recipeDescription:(NSString *)description pictureFile:(NSString *)picFile preparationTime:(NSString *)prepTime cookingTime:(NSString *)cookTime ovenTemperature:(NSString *)ovenTemp {
    NSArray *newRow = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:recipeID,title, description, picFile, prepTime, cookTime, ovenTemp, nil];
    NSLog(@"Before update, the number of args is %i", [newRow count]);
}
```

Do I have a type-o somewhere that I'm missing? You can see I'm passing in 7 objects to the array initializer but the NSLog method shows [newRow count] = 3.

Comment: nhahtdh is right. Look at his post below. In the method `initWithObjects`, passing `nil` as a parameter signals that that is the last object passed in. On a side note, I would recommend using an `NSURL` instead of an `NSString` for your picFile parameter, as NSURLs are more efficient when storing path data. Check out this question for more info on NSURLs and NSStrings: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769219/when-should-i-use-nsurl-instead-of-nsstring-and-vice-versa>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of the object passed in is `nil`, the rest of the argument will be ignored.

In this case, it seems that `picFile` is `nil`.