# Do I want to use NSString filePaths or NSURLs?

Tags: iphone, ios

Lots of classes have versions that work with NSStrings as a filePath or NSURLs. One example:

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
- (BOOL)copyItemAtURL:(NSURL *)srcURL toURL:(NSURL *)dstURL error:(NSError **)error
```

Is there an /explicit/ preference to use one over the other? I'm seeking a note in the documentation on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really up to you. However there are a lot of things that only use URL.

You can easily go from NSURL to path. but going the other direction will require some normalization.

using a path for instance with the scheme on it already will give you an improper url.

```
NSString *pathString = @"file://localhost/etc..../Document.txt";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathString];// This will not work.
```

you can however expect the path from a URL to be the correct path if initialized correctly.

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:pathString];
NSURL *sanePath = fileURL.path;
```

therefore you can get the correct url with 3 steps

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:pathString];
NSURL *sanePath = fileURL.path;

// You can at this point use the Path and expect it will be correct.

fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sanePath];

// You can at this point use fileURL and know it will be a correct fileURL with file://.
```

alternatively you can check the scheme to see if it is correct. but this is a problem I ran into with AVAsset because it will not load an NSURL from the path alone. It must be a fileURL

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Per [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7769339/1536348):

> "Generally for path related operations you should prefer NSURL over
>   NSString because the path information can be stored more efficiently
>   in NSURL (according to the class reference for NSFileManager). So I
>   would recommend that for your APIs you use also NSURL.
>
> Also NSURL has URLByAppendingPathComponent: and
>   URLByAppendingPathExtension: so convenience is served as well"